# How to create a row isolated heatmap with Highcharts

Tags: javascript, html, highcharts

I have a page that has a highcharts.com heat map on. That works well enough, but what I would like to is make each row independent an independent heat map, on the bottom row, that would be a heat map with a low value of 59 and high value of 621 spanning from yellow to red. Like wise, the second row would have a low value value 1 as yellow and 27 for the red value. In effect, it would be visually normalized through this sequences.

Does that make sense?

[image: Sample heat map]

Comment: Using single colorAxis you can set some stops and adjust data so it will look like there is more than one colorAxis - http://jsfiddle.net/j0vgeqxn/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately at this moment you can use only single colorAxis.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of. Thanks!